# Select according to rows increments

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database like this one :

```
ID | Twin | Tloss
0  |  300 | 250     #first entry 
1  |  301 | 250     #win;  score 1 - 0
2  |  302 | 250     #win;  score 2 - 0
3  |  302 | 251     #lose: score 2 - 1
4  |  303 | 251     #win;  score 3 - 1 
5  |  304 | 251     #end of match1 : Win  4 - 1
6  |  304 | 252     #lose; score 0 - 1
7  |  304 | 253     #lose; score 0 - 2
8  |  304 | 254     #lose; score 0 - 3 
9  |  304 | 255     #end of match2 : Lose 0 - 4
10 |  304 | 256     #lose; score 0 - 1
11 |  305 | 253     #win;  score 1 - 1
12 |  306 | 254     #win;  score 2 - 1 
13 |  306 | 255     #lose; score 2 - 2
14 |  307 | 255     #win;  score 3 - 2 
15 |  307 | 256     #end of match3 : Draw 3 - 3

....
```

I want to select all the ID corresponding to the match number "n",
considering a match is ended as soon as he wins 4 times or loses 4 times, draw is possible as the maximum number of round per match is 6.

I use SQL a lot since 1 months but I'm really lost on this one.

Could someone help me ?

Thanking you in advance,

Comment: . . What do your three data columns have to do with the comment that says whether something is a win or a loss?  Can you better explain the data?  Also, which database are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that some of the data above is broken (records 11-15, field tloss; record 5 should be Win 4 - 1). I also don't know what are the numbers 300 and 250 and how they change in the table. With these assumptions, this untested SQL might be want you want:

(revised after feedback from GordonLinoff)

```
SELECT @matchno := @matchno + 1 AS matchno
FROM (SELECT @matchno := 0) mn,
     (SELECT ID, Twin, Tloss, 
             IF((Twin - @twin) = 4
             OR (Tloss - @tloss) = 4
             OR ((Twin - @twin) = 3 AND (Tloss - @tloss) = 3),
                @twin := Twin AND @tloss := Tloss,
                0)
      FROM   matches, (SELECT @twin := 300, @tloss := 250) AS base
      WHERE  (Twin - @twin) = 4
      OR     (Tloss - @tloss) = 4
      OR     ((Twin - @twin) = 3 AND (Tloss - @tloss) = 3)
      ORDER BY ID
     ) endmatches
```

Comment: . . Clever idea and it might work.  However, your code doesn't work because the wins and ties are cumulative.  The mods don't help. However, with the same idea, you could store win information in local variables and also do the comparisons . . . that would probably work.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff. I have made an adjustment but I'm not sure if it was the kind of change you had in mind. Again it's untested but I'm not keen to invest boring work until the author provides further info. Also, why are the columns called twin/tloss? I would expect thost/tguest or so.

Comment: Yes, one data was broken, I edited my post.
My database can start at 300 and 250 or whatever else, I took those values as an example. Thank you for your work, I'll try this as soon as possible and i'll give you feedback

Comment: How come in record 11, tloss goes from 256 to 253? This is not consistent with the rest of the data.